# Touches in UIImage not firing

Tags: uiimageview

Everything is working except the graphics only work from the view! I have a UIImageView on a scrollView. The scroll-view is for my keyboard to raise my items behind the keyboard to see, but graphics did work before I added the scrollView, so I added the UIImage to draw on over the form. Now if I drag my finger from the view to the UIImageView it will draw, just not starting on the UIImageView. What am I doing wrong...

```
 - (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    drawImage = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:nil];
        drawImage.frame = self.view.frame;
    [self.graphicImageView addSubview:drawImage];
    mouseMoved = 0;
}


- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event{
mouseSwiped = NO;
UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
    lastPoint = [touch locationInView:self.graphicImageView];
    lastPoint.y -= 0;

}

 - (void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
        NSLog(@"Touches Moved");

        mouseSwiped = YES;

        UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
        CGPoint currentPoint = [touch locationInView:self.graphicImageView];
        currentPoint.y -= 0;

        UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(self.graphicImageView.frame.size);

        [drawImage.image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.graphicImageView.frame.size.width, self.graphicImageView.frame.size.height)];

        CGContextSetLineCap(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), kCGLineCapRound);

        CGContextSetLineWidth(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), 1.0); //width
        CGContextSetRGBStrokeColor(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0); //color red, green, blue, alpha
        CGContextBeginPath(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext());
        CGContextMoveToPoint(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), lastPoint.x, lastPoint.y);
        CGContextAddLineToPoint(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), currentPoint.x, currentPoint.y);
        CGContextStrokePath(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext());
        drawImage.image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

        lastPoint = currentPoint;

        mouseMoved++;

        if (mouseMoved == 10) {
            mouseMoved = 0;
        }
    }


- (void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    NSLog(@"Touches Ended");


    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];

    if ([touch tapCount] == 2) {
       // drawImage.image = nil;
    //    return;
    }


    if(!mouseSwiped) {
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(self.graphicImageView.frame.size);
        [drawImage.image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.graphicImageView.frame.size.width, self.graphicImageView.frame.size.height)];
        CGContextSetLineCap(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), kCGLineCapRound);
        CGContextSetLineWidth(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), 1.0);//width
        CGContextSetRGBStrokeColor(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0);  //color
        CGContextMoveToPoint(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), lastPoint.x, lastPoint.y);
        CGContextAddLineToPoint(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), lastPoint.x, lastPoint.y);
        CGContextStrokePath(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext());
        CGContextFlush(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext());
        drawImage.image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
    }
```

Comment: bydefault uiimageview touch is turned off... enable user enteraction

Comment: do you able to make line on imageview when you r moving finger

Comment: Enteraction is turned on.

Comment: When using my finger from the view yes does draw onto the entire area, however once I remove my finger and press down in any other location other than the view no it does not draw. To get this information I made the scrollview smaller than the view and the uiimageview smaller than the scrollview.

Comment: Note: I have no errors or warnings in my code.

Comment: Note: I can edit the form through the UIImageView with no problems. Just cannot draw on it.

Comment: I added the self.graphicImageView.exclusiveTouch=YES; during the move finger, but the image still does not draw(fire) from the UIImageView.

Comment: - (void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
        NSLog(@"Touches Moved");
        self.graphicImageView.exclusiveTouch=YES;
        mouseSwiped = YES;
.....        
        
- (void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    NSLog(@"Touches Ended");
    
    self.graphicImageView.exclusiveTouch=NO;
    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
    
    if ([touch tapCount] == 2) {
       // drawImage.image = nil;
    //    return;
    }

    
    if(!mouseSwiped) {
        ...

Comment: ok for starters I did enabled User Interaction from the attributes inspector but this was the wrong way.                               I had to:                                                           - (IBAction)switchtheswitch:(id)sender {

    if (theSwitch.on) {
        theSwitchLabel.text = @"Pen is On";
        drawImage.userInteractionEnabled=TRUE;
    }
    else {
        theSwitchLabel.text = @"Pen is Off";
        drawImage.userInteractionEnabled=FALSE;
    }

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok the UIImageView is now below the scrollView.

- (void)viewDidLoad {

  //KEYBOARD
  //---set the viewable frame of the scroll view---

  scrollView1.frame = CGRectMake(0, 44, 359, 457);

  //---set the content size of the scroll view---

  [scrollView1 setContentSize:CGSizeMake(359, 457)];

  [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                           selector:@selector(keyboardWasShown:)
                                               name:UIKeyboardDidShowNotification object:nil];

  [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                           selector:@selector(keyboardWillBeHidden:)
                                               name:UIKeyboardWillHideNotification object:nil];

  NSLog(@"viewDidLoad");
  drawImage = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:nil];
  drawImage.frame = self.view.frame;
  [self.view addSubview:drawImage];
  mouseMoved = 0;

  self.graphicImageView.userInteractionEnabled=TRUE;
  self->scrollView1.userInteractionEnabled=TRUE;

  [super viewDidLoad];

  }
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event{

  mouseSwiped = NO;
  UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];

  lastPoint = [touch locationInView:self.graphicImageView];
  lastPoint.y -= 0;

NSLog(@"Touches Began");
}

- (void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {

  ```
  NSLog(@"Touches Moved");

  mouseSwiped = YES;

  UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
  CGPoint currentPoint = [touch locationInView:drawImage];
  currentPoint.y -= 0;

  UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(drawImage.frame.size);

  [drawImage.image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, drawImage.frame.size.width, drawImage.frame.size.height)];

  CGContextSetLineCap(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), kCGLineCapRound);

  CGContextSetLineWidth(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), 1.0); //width
  CGContextSetRGBStrokeColor(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0); //color red, green, blue, alpha
  CGContextBeginPath(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext());
  CGContextMoveToPoint(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), lastPoint.x, lastPoint.y);
  CGContextAddLineToPoint(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), currentPoint.x, currentPoint.y);
  CGContextStrokePath(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext());
  drawImage.image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
  UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

  lastPoint = currentPoint;

  mouseMoved++;

  if (mouseMoved == 10) {
      mouseMoved = 0;
  }
  ```

  }

  - (void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {

  NSLog(@"Touches Ended");

  UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];

  if ([touch tapCount] == 2) {
      theSwitch.on = NO;
      drawImage.userInteractionEnabled=FALSE;
      theSwitchLabel.text = @"Pen is Off";
      doubleTapLabel.hidden = TRUE;
      return;
  }

  if(!mouseSwiped) {
      UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(drawImage.frame.size);
      [drawImage.image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, drawImage.frame.size.width, drawImage.frame.size.height)];
      CGContextSetLineCap(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), kCGLineCapRound);
      CGContextSetLineWidth(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), 1.0);//width
      CGContextSetRGBStrokeColor(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0);  //color
      CGContextMoveToPoint(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), lastPoint.x, lastPoint.y);
      CGContextAddLineToPoint(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), lastPoint.x, lastPoint.y);
      CGContextStrokePath(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext());
      CGContextFlush(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext());
      drawImage.image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
      UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

  }
  }

  - (IBAction)switchtheswitch:(id)sender {

  if (theSwitch.on) {
      theSwitchLabel.text = @"Pen is On";
      drawImage.userInteractionEnabled=TRUE;
      doubleTapLabel.hidden = FALSE;
  }
  else {
      theSwitchLabel.text = @"Pen is Off";
      drawImage.userInteractionEnabled=FALSE;
  }

}